# How to set the MUI Tabs by default close/in-active?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have done the 90% of tasks with Dynamic MUI Tabs with active and inactive, below are the points facing issues.

- Unable to set the default to inactive, due to type declaration as per MUI documentation suggested (TabPanelProps )
- If I change the variable type number to Boolean, getting issues in active and inactive as per the template code indexing type errors.
- Am using the MUI version 5 for tabbing

**Component:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { List, ListItem } from '@mui/material';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowDown';
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowUp';


interface TabPanelProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  index: number;
  value: number;
}

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`navigation-tab-panel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`navigation-tab-panel-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function a11yProps(index: number) {
  return {
    id: `navigation-tab-panel-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `navigation-tab-panel-${index}`,
  };
}

export default function BasicTabs() {
  let [currentTab, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: any) => {
    if (event) {
      if (currentTab === newValue) {
        setValue(0);
      } else {
        setValue(newValue);
      }
    }
  };

  return ( 
      <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <Box>
          <Tabs
            centered
            value={currentTab}            
            aria-label="tabs"
            TabIndicatorProps={{
              style: { display: 'none' },
            }}
          >
            {DATA.map((data, i) => (

              <Tab                
                key={data.navLabel}
                label={data.navLabel}
                onClick={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
                {...a11yProps(i)}
                icon={currentTab === i
                  ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon style={arrowIconsColor} />
                  : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon style={arrowIconsColor} />}
              />
            ))}
          </Tabs>
        </Box>

        {DATA.map((data, i) => (
          <TabPanel value={currentTab} key={data.page} index={i} {...a11yProps(i)}>
            <>
              <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <Grid container >
                  <Grid item md={12}>
                    <HeadingBox1>
                      <Typography variant="h5">{data.title}</Typography>
                    </HeadingBox1>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Box>
            </>
          </TabPanel>
        ))}
      </Box>
   
  );
}
```